# Add text to the last page of a PDF with python?

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to add text to the last page of a PDF that a user chooses. I can only get text to be added to the first page and it deletes all other pages. How can I add the text to the last page and keep all pages intact.

Thank you

edit - Code edited to include a for loop

```
import PyPDF2
from PyPDF2 import *
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
import os
from datetime import datetime


root=Tk()
root.withdraw()\

currentDay = datetime.now().day
currentMonth = datetime.now().month
currentYear = datetime.now().year

packet = io.BytesIO()
# Create a new PDF with Reportlab
can = canvas.Canvas(packet, pagesize=letter)
can.setFont('Helvetica-Bold', 7)
can.drawString(10, 170, "TEST")
can.drawString(45, 160, "TEST")
can.drawString(25, 150, "TEST")
can.drawString(50, 140, "___________ MONTH     __________ YEAR")
can.drawString(80, 140, str(currentMonth))
can.drawString(150, 140, str(currentYear))
can.showPage()
can.save()

username = os.getenv('username')
filename = askopenfilename()
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(filename, "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
for page_num in range(existing_pdf.numPages):
    page = existing_pdf.getPage(page_num)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)
name = (os.path.basename(filename))
name = name[:-4]
outputStream = open("C:\\Users\\" + username + "\\Desktop\\" + name + "-test.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()

root.destroy(
```

Comment: This line `page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)` retrieves the *first* page of the existing file, which your code manipulates and writes out. I don't see any code that even *reads* the other pages, let alone code that writes them out. It seems to me that your code should process all of the pages in the original (`for page in range(existing_pdf.numPages):`) and write them out, manipulating only the last one.

Comment: I am fairly new to Python. Could you elaborate on what code I need to write to perform this?

Comment: Doing `page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)` retrieves the first page. `0` means *first page*. But you want a to retrieve each page in order, so, `0, 1, 2, ...`. But because you don't necessarily know how many pages are in the file, your need a loop to iterate over them, with a loop counter that will depend on that number, which is given by `existing_pdf.numPages`. So, instead of setting `page` once, set it to each page in turn in a loop beginning `for page_num in range(existing_pdf.numPages):` . Inside the loop do `page = existing_pdf.getPage(page_num)` to fetch each page in turn.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I have added the for loop and it grabs the last page of the PDF and adds the text there, but then it deletes any of the preceding pages.

Comment: Is your code doing `output.addPage(page)`  for *every* page? Sounds like your code is only adding to the output the page it changes. Please [edit] your question to show the code as it is now. Or post a fresh question. We can't help you with code that is a different version from the one in your question.

Comment: I have edited the code in my original question.